# Messaging endpoint in bot framework?

Tags: bots

I'm trying to create my own bot in microsoft bot framework,it is asking the messaging endpoint in bot,what exactlty is this endpoint?

Answer (score 5):

Your messaging endpoint is the endpoint where messages will be sent to your bot.

A bot is just a web service. More specifically, a bot is an api that accepts posted messages. Like any service, your bot needs to be hosted somewhere.

You create a bot using the bot builder SDK (Node or C#) and deploy that code somewhere (could be Azure, could be AWS, could be on-premises). In your bot code you specify the **route** where messages will be sent to your bot (see node example below).

```js
server.post('/api/messages', connector.listen());
```

The botbuilder samples all use '/api/messages' as the route, so if you host your bot on samplebot.azurewebsites.net, then your messaging endpoint would be samplebot.azurewebsites.net/api/messages. However, you can make the route whatever you want.

Note: to register your bot you don't actually need to enter an endpoint - you can always add it later.

Comment: You have an example of how to send a message to the bot through the endpoint: "https://......api/messages". By postman for example?

Answer (score 3):

The messaging endpoint is the url where the messages, send to your bot, will arrive. It's the path to your sever where the code of your bot is hosted.

A endpoint url can look like this:

```
https://example.com/api/v1/botmessage
```

It routes to my server where the code is hosted and performs a post.

And here arrives the post with the message:

```
app.post('/api/v1/botmessage', connector.listen());
```

As you can see the connector starts to listen when a message comes in.

If there is something not clear, please ask me.

Comment: Hi there @StijnBrysbaert: what about other events, such as joining or leaving a channel / conversation? I appear to receive no requests on my endpoint for this and there seems to be no way to configure this.

Comment: You have an example of how to send a message to the bot through the endpoint: "https://......api/messages". By postman for example?